# pyarrow data types for columns that have lists of dictionaries?

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow

Is there a special pyarrow data type I should use for columns which have lists of dictionaries when I save to a parquet file?

If I save lists or lists of dictionaries as a string, I normally have to `.apply(eval)` the field if I read it into memory again in order for pandas to recognize the data as a list (so I can normalize it with `pd.json_normalize`)

column_a:

```
[
 {"id": "something", "value": "else"},
 {"id": "something2", "value": "else2"},
]
```

column_b:

```
["test", "test2", "test3"]
```

Just wondering if I should save this data as something else besides a string.

Edit - pasting a snippet of some raw JSON from Zendesk. The audits field has a field called **events** which is a list of dictionaries. Inside that, there can be other lists of dictionaries as well (**attachments** and inside that there is a list of dictionaries called **thumbnails**)

Are you able to use pa.map_ to handle situations like this? I sometimes need to retrieve data from these nested fields which I do not even know exist initially. In my current parquet dataset, the **events** field is just a single column
(string type) even though there are many nested fields within it.

```
udt = pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.string())
```

.

```
  "audit": {
    "id": ,
    "ticket_id": ,
    "created_at": "",
    "author_id": ,
    "events": [
      {
        "id": ,
        "type": "",
        "author_id": ,
        "body": "" ,
        "plain_body": "",
        "public": false,
        "attachments": [
          {
            "url": "",
            "id": ,
            "file_name": "",
            "content_url": "",
            "content_type": "image/png",
            "size": 2888,
            "width": 100,
            "height": 30,
            "inline": false,
            "deleted": false,
            "thumbnails": [
              {
                "url": "",
                "id": ,
                "file_name": "",
                "content_url": "",
                "mapped_content_url": "",
                "content_type": "image/png",
                "size": 2075,
                "width": 80,
                "height": 24,
                "inline": false,
                "deleted": false
              }
            ]
          },
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like an interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a df with "dictionary" and string columns, and the dictionaries all have the same keys (id, value in your case):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': pd.Series([
            {"id": "something", "value": "else"}, 
            {"id": "something2", "value": "else2"}
        ]),
        'col2': pd.Series(['foo', 'bar'])
    }
)

udt = pa.struct([pa.field('id', pa.string()), pa.field('value', pa.string())])
schema = pa.schema([pa.field('col1', udt), pa.field('col2', pa.string())])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema)
df = table.to_pandas()
```

If your dictionaries don't have the same keys or you don't know the keys of the dictionaries in advance, you can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': pd.Series([
            [('id', 'something'), ('value', '"else')],
            [('id', 'something2'), ('value','else2')],
        ]),
        'col2': pd.Series(['foo', 'bar'])
    }
)

udt = pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.string())
schema = pa.schema([pa.field('col1', udt), pa.field('col2', pa.string())])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema)
```

Note that the format for col1 is different (it is using a list of pairs instead of a dict).
Also you can't convert your table back to pandas as it is not supported (yet):

```
table.to_pandas()
>>> ArrowNotImplementedError: No known equivalent Pandas block for Arrow data of type map<string, string> is known.
```

Comment: Cool - thanks. I suppose I won't be able to utilize this yet because I need to get the data back to pandas to flatten it out for csv files or visualizations typically. I edited my question with a more complex real life example - would this pa.map_ handle nested fields within nested fields?

Comment: `pa.map_` won't work because the values need to be all of the same type. You could define a `pa.struct` for thumbnail, then define a `pa.struct` for attachment that would have a `pa.list_` of thumbnail. But considering the deeply nested nature of your data and the fact that there are a lot of repeated fields (many attachment/thumbnails in each record) they don't fit very well into a columnar format like arrow or a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your insight of lists of tuples for map types. I cannot find documentation anywhere that a dict cannot be made into a map, and it seems unintuitive to me that it can't. 